# muddled output while looping through CSV

Tags: bash

I have some files I would like to rename - trying to do this in a bash script as a learning excercise in bash, here is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER=/Users/annaleigh/Documents/data/geo_ibm/

while IFS=, read -r col1 col2
do
oldfile="$FOLDER""$col1"".SJ.out.tab"
newname="$FOLDER""$col2""$col1"".SJ.out.tab"

echo $oldfile
echo $newname

done < /Users/annaleigh/Documents/GitHub/muscle/rename.csv
```

However the results are...weird and I don't understand why

```
/Users/annaleigh/Documents/data/geo_ibm/16_9_5_18.SJ.out.tab
16_9_5_18.SJ.out.tabuments/data/geo_ibm/PM_3
```

`
This line is behaving as expected `oldfile="$FOLDER""$col1"".SJ.out.tab"`

However this line: `newname="$FOLDER""$col2""$col1"".SJ.out.tab"`
is appending $col1 and the extension to the front but with some kind of expansion? I have no idea what's happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens when your file contains DOS line endings. You can fix it by running below command.

```
dos2unix /Users/annaleigh/Documents/GitHub/muscle/rename.csv
```

See [BashFAQ#052](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/052)

Comment: But I guess `sed -i.bak 's/\r$//' file` would have the same effect

Comment: @Al okay, glad if I helped